# How to cancel a service when the device is restarted?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

I have two few questions regarding a service notification in android:

1. How to cancel the service if I chose to restart my device ?
2. How to keep the service running if I shut down my device and power it up again ?

Comment: At first http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/ second have you written the service? If not please go on [android.SE].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simple have to call the bootcompiled at the manifest file to recreate the service.

See below code:

```
<!-- To receive the Alarm Notification -->

    <receiver android:name=".RecreateTwoMonthAlarm" >         
        <intent-filter>             
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" /> 
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />         
        </intent-filter>     
    </receiver>
```

Now if you dont want to re create the service when the device get restarted then simple define the receiver in manifest without any BOOT_COMPLETED action.

as like below code:

```
    <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiverNotificationForTwoMonth" />
```

This is for receiver in My case. If you want the same thing for service then also you can do it.

hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks, but what if my service is defined in my application manifest? I mean:
<service android:name="android.services.MyService"/> 

Without any receivers ? Should I add this tag ?

Comment: Yes. Just simply change the receiver with the service and also change the respective intent name that are called while the service are getting calling.

Answer (score 0):

1)How to cancel the service if I chose to restart my device ?
Nothing to do, if there is not a BOOT_COMLETED receiver.

2)How to keep the service running if I shut down my device and power it up again ?
You should create a receiver class :

```
public class StartupReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         context.startService(new Intent(context,YourService.class));
     }
}
```

And declare in manifest file:

```
<receiver android:name=".StartupReceiver" >
   <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
  </intent-filter>
```